# Writing in a new text file

Tags: java, eclipse, parsing

I read a file and create a new file that copies some part of it, removes some lines and replaces them with others. The input arraystring raw is of type [Aaa,Bbb,Ccc,..] and is used to replace part of the line. 
In the new file, the non edited parts are printed properly, but the edited parts are printed this way. 1st one is printed, 2nd one not, 3rd yes, 4th no,5th yes... It looks like when I edit a line I erase the one below too. I tried removing out.write("\n") or scanner.nextLine() , but it didnt work either. Any ideas what could i try? Thanks in advance

```
For example:

    OLD TEXT: 
    .....
    LINE 6 / contains j(ac)
    LINE 7 / contains i(ac)
    LINE 8 / contains k(ac)
    LINE 9 / contains mp(ac)
    LINE 10 /contains bp(ac)
    .....

    NEW TEXT (NEW FILE):
     .....
    LINE NEW6 
    LINE NEW7 
    LINE NEW8 
    LINE NEW9 
    LINE NEW10 
    .....
```

---

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    new class();
    class.query();

    File file = new File("file");   
    File filenew = new File("file");

    try {


        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(filenew, true));
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file);

        while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
            String line = scanner.nextLine();
            if (line.contains("j(ac)")) {  
                String newline = line.replaceAll("/.*?/", "/"+raw1+"/");
                scanner.nextLine();
                out.write(newline);
                out.write("\n");
            } else if (line.contains("i(ac)")) {  
                String newline = line.replaceAll("/.*?/", "/"+raw2+"/");
                scanner.nextLine();
                out.write(newline);
                out.write("\n");   
            } else if (line.contains("k(ac)")) { 
                String newline = line.replaceAll("/.*?/", "/"+raw3+"/");
                scanner.nextLine();
                out.write(newline);
                out.write("\n");       
            }else if (line.contains("mp(k)")) {   
                String newline = line.replaceAll("/.*?/", "/"+raw4+"/");
                scanner.nextLine();
                out.write(newline);
                out.write("\n");           
            }else if (line.contains("bp(k)")) {    
                String newline = line.replaceAll("/.*?/", "/"+raw5+"/");
                scanner.nextLine();
                out.write(newline);
                out.write("\n");
            } else{ 
                out.write(line);
                out.write("\n");
            }
      }
      out.flush();
      out.close();
      scanner.close();

 } catch (IOException e)  {
     e.printStackTrace();
 }

}
}
```

Comment: You are scanning next line in every `else if` block

Comment: 1) Use a consistent and logical indent for code blocks.  The indentation of the code is intended to help people understand the program flow. 2) A single blank line of white space in source code is *always* enough.  Blank lines after `{` or before `}` are also typically redundant.

Comment: What is "type  [Aaa,Bbb,Ccc,..]"? You mean it's an array or other collections of strings, like `["Aaa", "Bbb", "Ccc"]`? Or a string that starts and ends with brackets, like `"[Aaa,Bbb,Ccc,..]"`? Or…?

Comment: More generally, can you give us some sample input (both your "arraystring" and a short file), the expected output, and what's wrong with the actual output?

Comment: As already pointed out by `Smit`, remove `scanner.nextLine()` from `if` and `elseif` blocks.

Comment: like ["Aaa","Bbb",...]

Comment: I have tried to remove it and the output is not good, cause it wont remove the line i want to edit. This way I will have both the old line and the new one. I only want to keep the new one, thats why i use scanner.nextLine()

Comment: @user2598911 When do you decide when you want new line to make edits? You need to provide exact details about when you want to edit, after editing do you want to edit that further, when do you want to stop editing and when do you want next line for editing? Also provide part of your input file

Comment: Its line.contains that shows when i want to edit and which line. That line that contains"" is the one I want to replace. And all ifs I include should be used and printed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how it suppose to go from the information you provided in your comment.

> 1. Its line.contains that shows when i want to edit and which line.
> 2. That line that contains"" is the one I want to replace.
> 3. And all ifs I include should be used and printed.

```
String line; 
while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
        // Get the line
        line = scanner.nextLine();
       
        // if line contains xxx then replace
        if (line.contains("j(ac)")) {  
            line = line.replaceAll("/.*?/", "/"+raw1+"/");

        } else if (line.contains("i(ac)")) {  
            line = line.replaceAll("/.*?/", "/"+raw2+"/");

        } else if (line.contains("k(ac)")) { 
            line = line.replaceAll("/.*?/", "/"+raw3+"/");

        }else if (line.contains("mp(k)")) {   
            line  = line.replaceAll("/.*?/", "/"+raw4+"/");
    
        }else if (line.contains("bp(k)")) {    
            line = line.replaceAll("/.*?/", "/"+raw5+"/");
           
        } 

        // Write the line with replaced items
        out.write(line);
        out.write("\n");
}
```

**Now what your code doing:**

```
 while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
            // get the line (very first line) and store that in "line"
            String line = scanner.nextLine();

            // check if line contains "j(ac)"
            if (line.contains("j(ac)")) { 

            // if "line" contains replace everything and save it to "newline" 
                String newline = line.replaceAll("/.*?/", "/"+raw1+"/");

            // get next line getting used for nothing (second line stored nowhere)
                scanner.nextLine();

            // write the newline to output file.
                out.write(newline);
                out.write("\n");
            } 


            // some more if else blocks executing same patterns explained above
            

             else{ 
            // if nothing contains in "line" then write to output file
                out.write(line);
                out.write("\n");
            }
      }
```